# What is the correct type of boost::mem_fn?

Tags: c++, boost

Am I able to implement the following function in C++?
I would like to keep the `myInstance` variable unspecified until the callback method is called, instead of containing it in a `boost::bind` instance.

```
MyClass *myInstance;

void call(/* boost::mem_fn */ callback)
{
    // Somewhere in this function, the operator()() method
    // is called on the callback instance

    callback(myInstance);
}

call(boost::mem_fn(&MyClass::myMethod));
```

I understand that `boost::mem_fn` is a function which returns a particular object, but I'm unsure of its type. The documentation says *unspecified* as its return type. One of the `boost::bind` constructors takes this type as a parameter, but I'm unable to find the actual declaration in its implementation. Also, am I even allowed to store my own instance of this particular type, or is this strictly for use by boost functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those cases where it seems that the compiler is doing some very magic stuff.

The reason there isn't really a well defined type is that the type returned from bosst::mem_fn is always assumed to be a template parameter of the function it's passed to. Let me show you an example:

std::for_each has a signature like this:

```
template <class InputIterator, class Function>
Function for_each (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f);
```

This little slice of magic has two template parameters, an InputIterator and a Function. These could have been called anything, but the names given to them describe how they will be used, really, are more self-documenting names than a real type. The type of InputIterator may well be something like `std::vector<foo>::iterator` - the point is that the compiler will automatically resolve what an "InputIterator" is at compile time. It can figure this type out for you.

The same is true of Function. As long as you pass it something that can be called - that is, has a version of `operator()` that is compatible with what gets called in `for_each`, then you never need to know what Function is.

So the short answer is, make your `call` function take a template parameter:

```
template<typename SomeSortOfFunction>
void call(SomeSortOfFunction callback)
```

and then the compiler should resolve `SomeSortOfFunction` to be whatever the type is that is returned from `boost::mem_fn`

Comment: "This is one of those cases where it seems that the compiler is doing some very magic stuff." Indeed...

Because of this, am I not allowed to store `callback` as a field in a class for later use without templating the class? How then, am I able to hold an instance of `boost::bind` without declaring its templated types? Thanks for your answer, Matt!

Answer (score 3):

The return type of `boost::mem_fn` is *unspecified*. You should use either Matt's approach (i.e. pass it as a template), or if separate compilation is important to you, use type erasure:

```
MyClass *myInstance;

void call(boost::function<void(MyClass*)> callback)
{
    callback(myInstance);
}

call(boost::mem_fn(&MyClass::myMethod));
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `mem_fn` is not something you should ever explicitly type or store.  It is generated at compile time via the types of the arguments.

It can, however, be stored via `std::function` (or `boost::function`).

The `operator()` signature of `men_fn` is the original method arguments with a possibly `const` pointer to the class prepended, and the same return value type.  Just create a `std::function` with that signature, and it can take the `men_fn` type and store it.

In short if you have a zero argument method for `class foo` that returns `void` try storing the men_fun in a `std::function<void(foo *)>`.